# What type of guatemala beetle is this?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

[image]

it was in Guatemala
it was really big like 4 inches 
sorry I don't have a better photo

Comment: Search on *Buprestidae* family.

Answer (score 1):

This [click beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_beetle) belongs to the species *Chalcolepidius rugatus*.

> According to the original description, this species is clothed, dorsally with white pubescence, with the sides of pronotum and elytra marginated by yellow, and ventrally, with brown pubescence. [source](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0085-56262002000300007)

---

[source](http://www.coleoptera-neotropical.org/paginas/3dm_familias/ELATEROIDEA/1sp/elateridae/Agrypninae/Chalcolepidius-rugatus.html)
[image]

[source](https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/272489-Chalcolepidius-rugatus)
[image]

---

### Distribution

[image]
[source](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0085-56262002000300007#fg684)